# All working locally fine but when uploaded some media files/players (mp3) and mp4 background doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, html, mp3, mp4

```
function playMusic() {
  var songs = [
    "pump.mp3",
    "ybwm.mp3",
    "bb.mp3",
  ];

  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length);
  var selectedSong = songs[randomIndex];

  var audio = new Audio(selectedSong);
  audio.addEventListener("ended", playNextSong);
  audio.play();
}

function playNextSong() {
  playMusic();
}
```

This is the function for music playing in the background once a button has been clicked. `ybwm.mp3` and `bb.mp3` work fine while `pump.mp3` doesn't.

```
function changeBackground() {
  var backgroundContainer = document.getElementById("background-container");
  backgroundContainer.style.opacity = 1;
  backgroundContainer.style.pointerEvents = "auto";

  var myvideo = document.createElement("video");
  myvideo.id = "myvideo";
  myvideo.autoplay = true;
  myvideo.muted = true;
  myvideo.loop = true;
  myvideo.style.position = "fixed";
  myvideo.style.top = "0";
  myvideo.style.left = "0";
  myvideo.style.width = "100%";
  myvideo.style.height = "100%";
  myvideo.style.objectFit = "cover";
  myvideo.style.zIndex = "-1";

  var source = document.createElement("source");
  source.src = "DANCE2.mp4";
  source.type = "video/mp4";

  myvideo.appendChild(source);
  backgroundContainer.appendChild(myvideo);
}
```

This is the code for the background after the button has been clicked, works fine locally but does not work once uploaded online.

I tried to change source type to video/mp4 or specifically tried to make it that. Expecting for the background to show up online but it didn't.
I also tried to convert the audio/x-generic to video/mp4. Someone had it work for them and it didn't work for me.
I changed/replaced files. I thought it might've been size at first so I changed to lower size mp3 file and that didn't change anything, it seems like only the two mp3 files work when online.

Comment: Can you add the console output?

Comment: @HazikArshad thank you a lot, i appreciate you so much you dont understand. After 9 or so hours, all I had to do was clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

very thankful to @HazikArshad. Upon opening console, I realised it was still running a command from the first ever js script I ran. Disabling cache helped to reset it. (Code was fine all along :'( )